# Java AES storing string to byteArray

Tags: java, encoding, arrays

I'm trying to encrypt a message that is in hex and it requires it to be stored into a byteArray. I got it working when i hard code the byte array but I can't get it to work when passed as an string.
The hardcoded byteArray looks like

```
byte secretKeyBytes[] = new byte[] {(byte) 0x80, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00,(byte)0x00, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x01};
```

So i want the user to pass a string like "0x80 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x01"

I want to know how to save this string as a byte[] array like above.
I have tried to use the .getBytes method but that does not work on the string
Can it some how be parsed?

I tried using the method posted on [Convert a string representation of a hex dump to a byte array using Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/140131/convert-a-string-representation-of-a-hex-dump-to-a-byte-array-using-java)
by @pfranza

```
        public static  byte[] fromHexString(String s) {
        String v[] = s.split(" "); 
        System.out.println(v.length);
        byte arr [] = new byte[v.length];
        int i = 0;
        for(String val: v) {

            arr[i++] =  Integer.decode("0x" + val).byteValue();
        }
        return arr;
```

I added a print statement to see the size of the array and it prints out 16 which is right. But i think it is not storing the values correctly in the byte array.
When i enter 0x80 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x01

I get java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "0x80"

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12495619/initialise-and-return-a-byte-array-in-java check this link ,some time it help to you.

Comment: An idea for parsing:  Use the String indexOf method to find the "0x", the substring method to get the next two characters and the Integer class's parseInt method radix=16 with a cast to get the value into a byte.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/140131/convert-a-string-representation-of-a-hex-dump-to-a-byte-array-using-java